# Category section not loading in admin product section for magento

Tags: magento

Category not showing in product add and edit section.. I got the following error on firebug console

**ReferenceError: bildCategoryTree is not defined**  - file name prototype.js

Pls help to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check for any extension installed.I have got the same issue after installing an extension which had got jquery included for admin.This was due to some jquery conflict
Please attach screen shot for reference